# Firebase Reference

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, reference

How can I reference the collection in the document I auto-id in Firebase?

```
final CollectionReference _olanaklar5 = _database
        .collection("Kategoriler")
        .doc("Hoteller")
        .collection("5_Yıldızlı")
        .doc() //======> here
        .collection("Olanaklar");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get list all document id with `doc.id`

```
List<String> _listDocId = [];
    await fireStore
        .collection("Kategoriler")
        .doc("Hoteller")
        .collection("5_Yıldızlı")
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
        _listDocId.add(doc.id);
      }
    });
```

and query in list doc id

```
for (var id in _listDocId) {
   final CollectionReference _olanaklar5 = _database
        .collection("Kategoriler")
        .doc("Hoteller")
        .collection("5_Yıldızlı")
        .doc(id)
        .collection("Olanaklar");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firebase auth, it's preferred to keep User's UID as doc, else you can use `.where()` as a query to match the fields in all documents. But as the app scales, it will be a hectic process and will consume many reads.